# Owin/Katana UseJwtBearerAuthentication Always Returns 401

Tags: authentication, bearer-token, owin-middleware

I need to implement JWT Bearer Authentication in both a .NET 4.6.1 Web API project, as well as a .NET Core 2.0 web project.

I successfully got the core project up and running with the this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#jwt-bearer-authentication) from Microsoft.

I'm following this [sample](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/01/15/using-json-web-tokens-with-katana-and-webapi.aspx) from Scott Allen for the .NET 4.6.1 project.

My 4.6.1 code looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Application requuires AD Bearer tokens for access
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = "https://validissuer.blahblah.com/",
                    ValidAudience = "https://validaudience.blahblah.com"
                }
            });
    }
```

The same token will correctly validate in the .NET Core API, but not the .NET 4.6.1 API, and I believe I'm missing something minor. Any ideas?

Side question: What are the best practices for what should be validated in a production environment? Both instances attempt to validate the issuer and audience, but should I consider validating anything else?

-Tim

Answer (score 2):

You need to set IssuerSigningKey property. If you don't know how to get the key manually, Here is an example to automatically resovle the IssuerSigningKey by authority:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var authority = "https://<your-authority>/";
        var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(authority);
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
                    ValidIssuer = "https://<your-authority>/",
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid)
                }
            });
    }

    private class OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver
    {
        private readonly OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig;

        public OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(string authority)
        {
            var cm = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{authority.TrimEnd('/')}/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            openIdConfig = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await cm.GetConfigurationAsync());
        }

        public SecurityKey[] GetSigningKey(string kid)
        {
            // Find the security token which matches the identifier
            return new[] { openIdConfig.JsonWebKeySet.GetSigningKeys().FirstOrDefault(t => t.KeyId == kid) };
        }
    }

    private static class AsyncHelper
    {
        private static readonly TaskFactory TaskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

        public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            TaskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
        {
            return TaskFactory.StartNew(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've assigned new instance of `TokenValidationParameters` to the corresponding property, I think, you should also provide a valid `IssuerSigningKey`.

```
    builder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode           = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters    = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
                ValidIssuer = "https://validissuer.blahblah.com/",
                ValidAudience = "https://validaudience.blahblah.com",
                IssuerSigningKey   = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecret")),
            }
        });
```